# How to tell if your app just opened

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

With the new iphones there are multitasking. This means that you don't have to re-start the app. I want to know what code gets called when you tap on the app to bring it up, but not when you start it for the first time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your application delegate, or observe the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification in another object.

These will be immediately followed by `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, respectively.